# Splice array rows if they have indexOf

Tags: javascript

I have these rows and want to delete all rows that have cell containing "undefined"

```
"rows":[
[0,"Peter", "undefined value"],
[3,"John", 90909090],
[5,"Mary","undefined"]
]
```

So, I need to remove rows 1 and 3

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: just use the `filter` method and create a new filtered array without those. Must you use `splice`?

Comment: No I need it in big array not this

Comment: I need to remove all rows that have indexOf "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), then [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on each item which is truthy if none of the items in each array includes `undefined` (string).

```js
let rows = [
  [0, "Peter", "undefined value"],
  [3, "John", 90909090],
  [5, "Mary", "undefined"]
];

rows = rows.filter(row => !row.some(v => typeof v === 'string' && v.includes('undefined')));

console.log(rows); // [ [ 3, 'John', 90909090 ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

just use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let rows = [
  [0, 'Peter', undefined],
  [3, 'John', 90909090],
  [5, 'Mary', undefined],
];

rows = rows.filter((row) => {
  return row.indexOf(undefined) === -1;
});

console.log(rows); // [ [ 3, 'John', 90909090 ] ]
```

if you mean that delete the array if it has a string cell contain 'undefined' as **string** you can go with this

```js
let rows = [
  [0, 'Peter', 'undefined value'],
  [3, 'John', 90909090],
  [5, 'Mary', 'undefined'],
];

rows = rows.filter((row) => {
  let isContainUndefined = false;
  row.forEach((element) => {
    if (String(element).includes('undefined')) {
      isContainUndefined = true;
      return;
    }
  });
  return !isContainUndefined;
});

console.log(rows); // [ [ 3, 'John', 90909090 ] ]
```